# Where does Cthulhu slumber in "The Call of Cthulhu"?

Tags: h-p-lovecraft, the-call-of-cthulhu

I know it's in the ocean, and off the coast of an uncharted island, but I'm not sure where the island is. I'd been thinking it was Antarctica but I recently realized I was confusing it with *At the Mountains of Madness*.

Comment: You probably got a downvote because Lovecraft gives us the exact location in the story. Read my answer below.

Comment: @AndresF.   Fair enough. I read the story a few years ago and don't have a copy of it on hand though, so it's not something I had on hand to look up.

Comment: I didn't give you the downvote :) But anyway, every Lovecraft story is easily found online... which is what I just did.

Comment: Alright, so don't ask questions about books without obtaining and searching the book first. Check!

Comment: @Sterno I don't think you need to be that strict, but doing some research before asking something simple is always a good idea. :)

Comment: @IanPugsley I'd done some googling, but hadn't hit upon R'lyeh as the thing I was looking for. Anyway, will keep in mind for next time!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the [Wikipedia article on R'lyeh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%27lyeh#cite_note-The_Call_of_Cthulhu-0):

> - Lovecraft claims R'lyeh is located at 47°9′S 126°43′W. *[H.P Lovecraft, "The Call of Cthulhu" (1928)]*
> - Writer August Derleth, a contemporary correspondent of Lovecraft and co-creator of the Cthulhu Mythos, placed R'lyeh at 49°51′S 128°34′W. *[Derleth, A. The Black Island (1952)]*
>
> The latter coordinates place the city approximately 5,100 nautical miles (9,400 km) from the actual island of Pohnpei (Ponape), the location of the fictional "Ponape Scripture". Both locations are close to the Pacific pole of inaccessibility (48°52.6′S 123°23.6′W), a point in the ocean farthest from any land mass.

Comment: Right next to a giant ridge in the ocean floor.....http://maps.google.com/maps?q=-47%C2%B09%27,+%2B123%C2%B043%27&mid=1327323656

Answer (score 12):

Lovecraft gives us the precise location:

> Then, driven ahead by curiosity in their captured yacht under Johansen's command, the men sight a great stone pillar sticking out of the sea, and in S. Latitude 47°9', W. Longitude l23°43', come upon a coastline of mingled mud, ooze, and weedy Cyclopean masonry which can be nothing less than the tangible substance of earth's supreme terror - the nightmare corpse-city of R'lyeh [...]

I wonder what Google Maps shows there... :P

Source: the full story [available online.](http://dagonbytes.com/thelibrary/lovecraft/thecallofcthulhu.htm)

Comment: If I didn't get the signs wrong... http://maps.google.com/maps?q=-47%C2%B09',+%2B123%C2%B043'&hl=en&ie=UTF8&ll=-45.665544,130.217709&spn=37.304057,81.123047&sll=-47.15,-123.716667&sspn=0.008858,0.019805&vpsrc=6&t=w&z=4

Comment: @badp, a shame there is nothing interesting there :P

Comment: OR IS THERE?? *puts on conspiracy theory hat* Only one way to know!

Comment: @badp I checked Satellite, Webcam, normal view, and Google Earth - nothin'.  Anybody else in to charter a boat to take soundings of the supposed location of R'lyeh? :)

Comment: @IanPugsley - no thank you,  I would like to keep my sanity.

Comment: Interestingly enough, around the coordinates of where that city is supposed to be, is an unidentified sound called upsweep. Though i doubt its a Great Old One it is kind of cool. The point is about 480 nautical miles from Dereleths R'lyeh, 640 nautical miles from HPLs R'lyeh and 690 nautical miles from Point Nemo. Just something some of you might find interest to look into.